# What are the consequences of modifying a node module?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have a simple `nodeJS` web server project I've installed using `npm`.

To run the server I run:

```
npm install && npm run serve
```

My concern arises when I want to modify one of the NPM modules, but afraid that they will get lost passing the project to another user.

Why? - because the user will run `npm install` again.

Does that mean that they will have two node modules with the same name? Will it overwrite my modifications to the module? What will happen?

Would love some clarity, please.

Comment: A better question is "why are you modifying the module, instead of looking up how to extend it in your own code, instead?" because the whole point of a node module is that it's the same code for everyone when they run `npm install`. You don't change anything inside `./node_modules/` yourself.

Comment: Technically you _could_ modify your dependency, granted you commit that dependency as part of your repository codebase so that your modifications can be reproduced, but as Mike says, this is an antipattern to the modular approach that Node.js and npm encourage for development.

Comment: You should not modify modules as they are external dependencies. I had to modify a package one time, but only because of a bug in that specific package. At worst, fork it and make it a local dependency of your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely it will get lost if another user npm installs again. If it is very important then, you should keep the track of the changes in your node modules. Before deploying you should make those changes in them.

He will not have 2 node_modules but will update the old one and your changes will be lost in his system.